# Plot specific column after DataFrame aggregation

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I would like to plot a bar and line graph of specific columns.

Using `agg` function I got as many new columns as there are functions.
What can I do if I want to plot only column  sum of **`A`** and mean of **`B`** column ?

[image]

Below you can find my code, where all columns are plotted.

```py
index=pd.date_range('2013-1-1 00:00', '2013-12-31  23:00', freq='1h')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index),2),index=index, columns=['A','B'])

df2=df.groupby(lambda x: x.month).agg({'A' : [np.mean, np.sum], 'B': np.mean}) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = df2['A'].plot(kind="bar");plt.xticks(rotation=0)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),df2['B'],marker='o')
```

Could you be able to give me some hints how to solve this ?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a hierarchical index.  So you just need to select the right columns using the `tuple` syntax.

So instead of:

```
ax = df2['A'].plot(kind="bar")
```

use:

```
ax = df2[('A', 'sum')].plot(kind="bar")
```

and instead of:

```
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),df2['B'],marker='o')
```

use:

```
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),df2[('B', 'mean')],marker='o')
```

Putting it all together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sbn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

index = pd.date_range('2013-1-1 00:00', '2013-12-31  23:00', freq='1h')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index),2),index=index, columns=['A','B'])
df2 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.month).agg({'A' : [np.mean, np.sum], 'B': np.mean}) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = df2[('A', 'sum')].plot(kind="bar", alpha=0.7)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),df2[('B', 'mean')],marker='o', c='navy', linewidth=4)
```

gives you a nice graph:
[image]

Comment: Do you know how to plot legend in this graph ? Using label doesn't seem to work...